# Return to route from custom id, based on primary key in URL in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application which displays data based on the *"Name"* column header in a table, which is declared as the id in the routing config:

```
{controller}/{action}/{name}
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Job", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

The name is not the primary key as pages will display multiple rows with the same name, based on the query string. The applications runs well and CRUD functions are working. The only problem I have is redirecting the user to the display page after posting from the "Edit" or "Delete" pages, as I want to return the user to the page displaying the rows of data with the same "Name", but I can only seem to access the ID, (primary key) which is not what I want

For Example:

**localhost:8888/Home/Job/Jonathan**

```
Jonathan | Column2 | Column3
Jonathan | Column2 | Column3
Jonathan | Column2 | Column3
Jonathan | Column2 | Column3
```

When editing or delete a row, the URL will be: /Home/edit?id=48, and I'm trying to figure out how I can get the "Name" column field (within the controller), based on the "ID" of the selected row, and return the user to the page with that "Name" in the URL after posting.

It's pretty simple to do within the View, for a back button:

```
@{
    var name= Model.Name;
}

<a href="../home/job/@name" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
```

But I can't seem to figure it out for the routing when posting a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, by passing the "Name" into the query string as well, using the Html.ActionLink, you can then access the "Name" in the URL to use with the controller.

**Link:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", new { id=item.id, name=item.Name})
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Table1 table1)
    {
        var query = RouteData.Values["name"];

        var back = "../job/" + query;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Entry(table1).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectPermanent(back);
        }

        return View(table1);
    }
```

Comment: I think you could also write a query to find the name given the id, and then use that as well.  Maybe something like: (Item)(_db.Entry.Single(x => x.id)).Name